# Is there a link to the search instructions on the site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

I found a link to the new [search instruction page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) on the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/), but I can't seem to find one on StackOverflow itself.  I looked at the FAQ and About links with no luck.  I would have expected a little question mark next to the search box with a handy hover effect to show me that's how I get to the search instructions.  Am I just missing it or do I really have to remember (tag/bookmark/...) it?  If there isn't one, perhaps one could be added.

Answer (score 3):

There's a link on the sidebar of a searched page if it turns up limited results. It doesn't seem to appear if there are a lot of results for your query.

[alt text http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/9016/picture16dfh.png](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/9016/picture16dfh.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can also enter nothing in the search box and just press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

The faq does contain a section on search now, at

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#search

Comment: Now that's completely intuitive.  :-(